# Updating a foreign key of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I hope this makes sense. 
I have  two tables. Table 2 has a foreign key to id of Table 1. Table 1 is added with new data based on the created date. How can I update the table 2 foreign keys with new id.

```
Table 1:
╔═════════════════════════╗
║     id code createdDate ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║     1  xxx  05/07/2013  ║
║     2  xyz  05/07/2013  ║
║     3  xxx  07/07/2014  ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

Table 2:

```
╔════════════════════════════════╗
║     id codeId  description     ║
╠════════════════════════════════╣
║     1   1      xxx description ║
║     2   2      xyz description ║
╚════════════════════════════════╝
```

I have to update the Table2 codeId to 3 and 1. i can't delete the old entries of Table1 for historical purposes.
I disabled the foreign key and did create a query which returns in multiple columns in subquery.

```
UPDATE TABLE2 
SET    CODEID = (SELECT ID 
                 FROM   TABLE1 
                 WHERE  CODE = (SELECT T.CODE 
                                FROM   TABLE2 
                                       INNER JOIN (SELECT CODE, 
                                                          MAX(CREATEDDATE) AS 
                                                          maxDate 
                                                   FROM   TABLE1 
                                                   GROUP  BY CODE) tm 
                                               ON T.CODE = tm.CODE 
                                                  AND T.CREATEDDATE = tm.MAXDATE 
                               ))
```

Comment: I cannot discern a question here.  What is it that you are trying to accomplish or what error are you getting?

Comment: How are table 1 and table 2 linked? There appear to be no fields shared other than the foreign key you wish to update (table 2 doesn't have the `code` field your SQL seems to imply).

Comment: Is the id column of table 1 identity column?

Comment: @paqogomez Table2 codeId column is FK to Table1( identity column). I have to update the Table2 foreign key references after the Table1 has been modified.

Comment: @KiranHegde Both the Table1 and Table2 id's are identity columns

Comment: @AdrianWragg When the tables are initially created, the data was loaded using Import/Export Wizard. And codeId of Table2 references id(identity column) of Table1. Now the data is changed in Table1 based on the other parameters with new created date. So I want to change the codeId in Table2 to point to newly created entries. And the old entries and new entries still have the same code(e.g. XXX) on Table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you have want to update your Table2 to a newer version or something of the Table1 record. In your structure, you only have Table2.codeId as a link to Table1. So you will need kind of a mapping table which tells you for each record in Table1 which is the relating record with the latest version:

```
SELECT t1.id,tmp.latestId
FROM Table1 t1
   JOIN (SELECT code,max(id) latestId
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY code
        HAVING count(*)>1) tmp ON tmp.code=t1.code
```

This will only work because of the identity columns. It can also be done by the date column which will require an additional join on a subquery.

Now you can use the mapping table to join Table2. I think this is better than using `Table1.code` and `Substring(Table2.description)` since it is more reliable to work with unique ids.

```
WITH cte (codeId,lastestId)
AS (
SELECT t1.id,tmp.latestId
FROM Table1 t1
   JOIN (SELECT code,max(id) latestId
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY code
        HAVING count(*)>1) tmp ON tmp.code=t1.code
)       
UPDATE t2 SET codeId=cte.lastestId
FROM cte
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.codeId=cte.codeId
```

Comment: Your solution works only a small typo in update statement. It should be codeId instead of code_id

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
;WITH MAXT 
     AS (SELECT CODE, 
                MAX(CREATEDDATE) createdDate 
         FROM   TABLE1 
         GROUP  BY CODE), 
     MAXTOTAL 
     AS (SELECT T1.* 
         FROM   TABLE1 T1 
                INNER JOIN MAXT T2 
                        ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE 
                           AND T1.CREATEDDATE = T2.CREATEDDATE) 
UPDATE T2 
SET    codeid = T1.ID 
FROM   TABLE2 T2 
       INNER JOIN MAXTOTAL T1 
               ON T1.CODE = LEFT(T2.DESCRIPTION, 3) 

SELECT * 
FROM   TABLE2
```

You can see a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55188/10)

Comment: I guess my question was not completely clear. Your solution works only if I want to use description column and code names are of fixed length. In actual tables the  description does not start with the code names.